# Writing binary file bytes to clipboard

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to read binary file bites , convert it into string and then write it on the disk .

Basically this is my code

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\1.exe")
Clipboard.SetText(bytes.ToString)
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\2.exe", bytes)
```

It works in reading/writing file , but it fails to copy the bytes into the clipboard , what i get is "`System.Byte[]`" on the clipboard .. so how can i read some binary file bytes and store them / copy to clipboard ?

Comment: You say "It fails to copy the bytes into the clipboard , what i get is `System.Byte[]`". What else do you expect to get there?

Comment: The file bytes it self . I still noob in programming world , so am I missing something ? . Can store the bytes in a text file ?

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the file once it's on the clipboard? You certainly don't need to put them there to create `2.exe`.

Comment: Well I want to store the bytes in the application and then write these bytes into a binary file on Disk .

Comment: Don't get it. Why do you need the clipboard anyway? If you want to convert it to a string, why are you giving it an exe extension, it sure as heck won't execute, not unless you convert it back..

Comment: File.Copy(fromFile, ToFile) ????

Answer (score 2):

When you use Clipboard.SetText() then you should put **text** on the clipboard.  An EXE file does not contain text, it contains a program.  Try opening your 1.exe file with Notepad to see what that looks like.  Not text.

You *can* put a binary file on the clipboard.  That could look like this:

```
    Dim files = New String() {"c:\windows\notepad.exe"}
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, files)
```

Now switch to Windows Explorer and press Ctrl+V.  You've got a copy of Notepad.exe

If you just want a copy of a file then use File.Copy():

```
    System.IO.File.Copy("c:\1.exe", "c:\2.exe")
```

Which doesn't just copy the bytes in the file, it also makes sure that the attributes of the file are set correctly.

Comment: Ok , How can I store the bytes in a string and then write to the desk ?

Comment: I don't want to copy it , I want to write 2.exe to desk in case of 1.exe doesn't exist

Comment: I have no idea what "write 2.exe to desk" might mean.  If you are talking about copying a file to the desktop then use Environment.GetFolderPath() to get the path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your bytes into a string:

```
Dim text as String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
Clipboard.SetText(bytes.ToString)
```

However, as Neolisk mentions, this is not really going to help since you really are reading a binary, not a text-file

Comment: Well I want to store the bytes in the application and then write these bytes into a binary file on Disk . (Without having 1.exe on the disk)

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes.ToString
```

takes the string representation of the array, rather than its contents. Reference types return their typename from ToString(), unless they override it to do something different.

What you're really looking to do is *convert* the byte array to a string. For this, use `Encoding.GetString(bytes)` - where you'll need to use a static member of `Encoding` like `Encoding.UTF8` as the appropriate instance - depending on what representation of a string your bytes encode.

**edit #1**: I didn't actually notice what you were reading. What do you expect the text representation of an executable file to be? What meaning is there to placing it on the clipboard?

Comment: My main goal is to store 1.exe bytes in the application and then write it to desk .

Comment: What do you mean by 'store' and what are the 'file bytes' if there is no `1.exe`? Please explain what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: What I mean is : I want to store "1.exe" bytes as a string / byte array and then write it to desk . I don't want to read it and then write it

Comment: What does the clipboard have to do with it? Why did you include this in the original sample? I can't see what this has to do with your problem.